# Gmail DMARC error for sending mail from another domain

Tags: gmail, mailgun, google-workspace

I have domain on google like `mydomain.com`, but I'm sending emails from mailgun where domain is `mg.mydomain.com`. 
Now I have error with DMARC. 
Is there some way to let `mg.mydomain.com` send emails with `mydomain.com` domain? Or some another to avoid this problem?